# Android Emulator shows same output every time

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-build

Being new to the **Eclipse/Phonegap** environment and **Android**, I have tried for days now (but to no avail) to understand as to why the emulator shows the same output every time I run an app.

May it be some another app and may it's *index.html* or *homepage.html* file contains different text, the output is the same as it was when I ran the First app on the system (about two weeks ago)...

*It seems like it is referencing the very first app everytime the Emulator runs an app, which is certainly* UNWANTED :)

Comment: How are you doing any of this? Please provide details. Are you editing the files in the `platforms/` folder or in the base `www` folder? Are you deploying from Eclipse or using the cordova-cli? What emulator are you using?

Comment: Hi @DawsonLoudon well yes, I am editing the file (index.html) in the /assets/www/ folder.. and deploying from Eclipse.. and then obviously its own Emulator..

Comment: Are you using cordova CLI? I'm guessing you're not building your app properly. You need to use `cordova build android` command to build the app the to convey the changes you made in `www` folder to platform folders

Comment: No @AtanuCSE not using Cordova CLI. Kindly tell me how to move ahead w/o the same. There must be a Non-CordovaCLI way to convey any changes in the www folder to the platform.